# Why i got a null message when retrieveng an string line from a file in java

Tags: java

I tried to retrieve a single line of text from a text file in java, and indeed i got what i expect but at the end it adds a null reference, but i don't know why. here my code:

```
public class EncryptDecryptFile {


public void writeDecryptionFile(String message) {

    File f;
    FileWriter writeArchive;

    try {

        f = new File("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Training\\DecryptionFile.txt");
        writeArchive = new FileWriter(f);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writeArchive);
        PrintWriter text = new PrintWriter(bw);

        text.write(message+"\n");
        text.close();
        bw.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}

public String readEncryptionFile() {

    File file = new File("C:\\Test\\EncryptionFile.txt");
    
    String line = "";
    
        try (
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                
            
            while (true) {
               
                line = br.readLine();
                if (line != null) {
                    
                    System.out.print(line);
                    
                } else {
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
     
        e.printStackTrace();
    
    }   
    
    return line;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EncryptDecryptFile file = new EncryptDecryptFile();
    file.writeDecryptionFile("Hello World!!!");
    System.out.println(file.readEncryptionFile());

}

}
```

The result is as follows

Hello World!!!
null

Where is that null coming from ?

I appreciate any help :(

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `line` and printing it at the end of `System.out.println(file.readEncryptionFile());` at that time it must be `null` (or the loop would not end). Solution, don't print it. Just do

```
file.readEncryptionFile();
```

Note: You also print with-in `readEncryptionFile()`

Answer (score 1):

Do not do

```
System.out.println(file.readEncryptionFile());
```

You are already printing it out in this method, so just calling

```
file.readEncryptionFile();
```

should suffice.

Of course you do not need to return a String from this method.

Alternative in the `readEncryptionFile`, create a `StringBuilder` Object and append to that if the `line` is not null, then return the String of the `StringBuilder` Object.

Comment: Bro you're a master. Sorry for the dump Question, and yes you're rigth, the method return a string, theres no need to use a system.print. Thanks a lot for your cooperation. :)